# Run vuejs development server with SSL (to serve over HTTPS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, vue.js

*Important Detail & Workaround:* I've come across this: "[Deprecating Powerful Features on Insecure Origins](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)"

This explains that HTTPS is enforced on external hosts. I have my development environment on my laptop and, on the weekend I SSH into that box, which is why I ran into this problem yesterday. I run the `vuejs` dev server remotely on the laptop, making it listen to `0.0.0.0` and open the page on my desktop. This causes the problem.

I've tried using SSH port forwarding to `localhost`. This worked and is an acceptable workaround for me.

The original question *still remains valid*. I will leave it open for now.

---

I'm working with a JS API which requires SSL (WebRTC). So to do development, I need to run the dev server over HTTPS. How can I do that with vuejs?

I've quickstarted the project using webpack. I found some links explaining how to run webpack-dev-server over SSL but I don't know how to do that with a vuejs application. I'm incredibly green considering everything that's JavaScript & NPM. The webpack links all mention a config file, but there is no such file in my project. The closest I see is the "main.js" but there is absolutely no configuration in there.

In essence, what I have is the result of the following steps:

```
mkdir demo
cd demo
npm install --save-dev vue-cli
./node_modules/.bin/vue init vuetifyjs/webpack-advanced demo

# Use the defaults here (except for "Vue build" I used "Runtime-only")

cd demo
npm install
npm run dev  # <-- This is the command I would like to use SSL in
```

Comment: @exhumai Hi i can help you for node.js but why vue.js should be different??

Comment: I don't really know. It is pretty much the first application I am trying to write in JS using a dev web server like this. I have not used webpack by itself just yet. I find the development workflow with vuejs easy to get started with. Except that I am now struggling with the HTTPS issue

Comment: i just put an example based on express fs and https adding certificat based on key generated by openssl needed. Regards.

Comment: Are you sure you need the Webpack dev server to be https? The dev server is purely for live reloading (as you change the code, the website will use the new code without a full refresh), it is only used in development and shouldn’t interact with this API you mentioned. Maybe you need an actual node server to be https? Also Vue doesn’t have anything to do with https, Vue is client side and https is a server issue.

Comment: @EricGuan exhuma just started a node project i think he don't really known how to drive webpack on  https isn't really a matter here the way is how to add and generate from nodejs own SSL i guess is what i understand. For doing a webpack on https what we have to do is just to call the web pack with a https as arguments like this : `webpack-dev-server --https` in this cas we don't worries about how to do them self. But if you got a solution about this take the car and drive him if you wanted. Let me known. Regards.

Comment: @EricGuan The API I am using is not a *remote* API. It's a standard browser-API. This problem is that (as explained in an update I've just added to the original question) the web-page/script which calls this page is served over an insecure connection. In production it will not use the vue dev server. I only use it now for the auto-reloading & co.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: Which site would you recommend moving this to? I've considered them before posting, but it seemed to me that SO would be the most appropriate. While it is not about source code, it is still related to a programming environment. In addition to the sites you named, it doesn't fit Serverfault either.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you still have this problem or if any other person still encounters it but I found a solution.

Follow the instruction above to generate an openssl key and cert in your working folder.

In **/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js** change this line from:

```
 key: {

    type: 'string',

    describe: 'Path to a SSL key.',

    group: SSL_GROUP

  },

  cert: {

    type: 'string',

    describe: 'Path to a SSL certificate.',

    group: SSL_GROUP

  },
```

to:

```
key: {

    type: 'string',

    describe: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),

    group: SSL_GROUP

  },

  cert: {

    type: 'string',

    describe: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),

    group: SSL_GROUP
  },
```

then set

```
argv.https = true;
```

That is all I had to do to have my code served from `https`.

*Note that the command line will still read **http://localhost:8080**, but when you use `https` in the browser, your app will be displayed after warning from the browser*

Answer (score 1):

Requirement **openssl** installed :

First we have to **generate SSL certificat based on a key** made by **openssl** and without pass phrase cos this will **generate an error**.

> nodejs https>node server.js
>   _tls_common.js:87
>           c.context.setKey(options.key);
>                     ^ Error: error:0907B068:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read ...

Go inside your project start to create key & certificat :

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

> -nodes : Don't encrypt the private keys at all.

Install the packages needed for your project : (--save to add to package.json)

```
npm install express --save
npm install https --save
npm install fs --save
```

now create the server file :

```
touch server.js
nano server.js
```

Copy/Paste : to server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var app = require('express')();
var options = {
   key  : fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
   cert : fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Started!');
});
```

In this cas we don't use 443 port because is already used by services, so i use the port 3000 unused by any app...

Comment: but that does not use the vuejs server? Not quite sure I understand. I already have something similar like that using uwsgi. But that does not help with `.vue` files.

Comment: @exhuma If you want i use vuejs i need you part of server. post it. i need too the requieremnt modules if is needed.

Comment: There is nothing special to post. Give me a second. I'll edit the original question to add an example of how to set up a vue project (basically giving a file tree like the one I have).

Comment: @exhuma ok thanks or send me the url where you did it ;). I have to go in 15min. and came back in 5hours.

Comment: Just edited the original question. I'll be gone in a few minutes as well. And then it will be night time over here. So I'll probably see your reply tomorrow :P

Comment: @exhuma ok no problem i will add my answer this night and we meet tomorrow ;) good night.